# Display mysql row after login

Tags: php, mysql

Hi there this is my first post here and I'm in desperate need of help.
I am developing a website for a member based travel and holiday company, after the user successfully logs in it redirects to search-flights.php, I would like to display the users details in my-account.php using the login details to retrieve the specific mysql row. How would I go about doing this? I have researched this for a long while and I have not found any solution remotely close to what I need to do
Here is some of my code, please keep in mind that I am fairly new to php and mysql

```
    <form method="POST" id="login-form" action="./Scripts/checklogin.php">
  <fieldset class="userdata">
    <p id="form-login-username">
      <label for="modlgn-username">User Name</label>
      <input id="modlgn-username" name="myusername" class="inputbox" size="18" type="text">
      <p id="form-login-password">
        <label for="modlgn-passwd">Password</label>
        <input id="modlgn-passwd" name="mypassword" class="inputbox" size="18" type="password">
        </p>
    <p id="form-login-remember">
      <label for="modlgn-remember">Remember Me</label>
      <input id="modlgn-remember" name="remember" class="inputbox" value="yes" type="checkbox">
      </p>
    <input type="image" class="move" value="Login" src="images/Login.png" alt="Log in Button" title="Log in" />
    <input name="option" value="com_users" type="hidden">
    <input name="task" value="user.login" type="hidden">
    <input name="return" value="aW5kZXgucGhwP0l0ZW1pZD00MzU=" type="hidden">
    <input name="e4b8befc8354bc2ee27d826c9dcc850f" value="1" type="hidden"> </fieldset>        
  </form>   



     <?php
// check-login.php
$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username="********"; // Mysql username
$password="********"; // Mysql password
$db_name="choliday_members"; // Database name
$tbl_name="members"; // Table name
// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
// username and password sent from form
$myusername=$_POST['myusername'];
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword'];
// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1){
// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
session_register("myusername");
session_register("mypassword");
header("location:../members/search-flights.php");
}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
?>
```

Comment: store the user_ID to session and use it to recall user details from sql whenever needed.

Comment: How do so many people who are brand new to PHP and MySQL keep getting jobs writing web sites that require this expertise? This is like the 20th one of these questions I've seen tonight.

Comment: And note that mysql_ methods are deprecated in favour of PDO and/or mysqli_

Comment: @Barmar: yes, sometimes I get the feeling SO is more getting like thedailyWTF.

Comment: Problem is in redirecting or selecting row ?

Comment: Before Using Session it is needed to be initialized in php

So use :


session_start();
// store session data
$_SESSION['key']=value;

And access it whenever required.

Answer (score 0):

session_register is deprecated....

Use $_SESSION[] instead ;)

Something like:

```
$_SESSION['username'] = $myusername;
```

And, then... if u manage well the sessions, in the my-account you can use the $_SESSION with the values of login...

Answer (score 0):

We won't write code for you, but to help you a little, here is what is wrong with your code:

1. Don't `SELECT *`, select what you need, nothing more.
2. Don't store passwords, but hashes instead.
3. Use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead of mysql.
4. What if a user has slashes in his password?
5. If you are actually getting paid to do this job, please get more knowledge first. Learn how to create a decent web application. Teach yourself concepts like [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) et al. Code like yours give PHP and web development its bad name.
6. Do correct and failsafe error handling.

Good luck in learning PHP!

Answer (score 0):

After authenticating the user, you will need to generate and `persist` a unique key for this users session.

`$_SESSION['key] = 'aksbh7823b5iubsvd874bosidhvjbi3i4btv'`;

Normally, this would be a unique string, which you can store in a sessions table, along with the users identity (primary key).

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO sessions (`key`, `user_id`) VALUES ('$_SESSION['key']', '$userId');
```

By placing this unique key in the global `$_SESSION` scope you can now fetch this value from another request, providing the session still exists.

```
<?php
  session_start();

  $key = $_SESSION['key'];
  $sql = "
    SELECT b.* FROM sessions AS a
    INNER JOIN users AS b ON b.id = a.user_id
    WHERE key = '" . $key ."'
  ";
  $result = mysql_query($sql);
?>
```

Please note that the use of `mysql_query` (and the lack of value escaping) above is considered **very** insecure and I would strongly advise on using the `PDO` or `mysqli` libraries to avoid SQL injection.